# Does diffClamp method is removed in Reanimated v2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

In the previous version I see the Reanimated have a method naming diffClamp but in v2 is there removed or replaced?

[Reanimated v1 docs of diffClamp](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/diffClamp/)

or how to do diffClamp like previous version?
Thanks